# Clone a Poetry project onto my PC and continue using Poetry

Tags: python, github, python-poetry

It seems a simple question. I forked someone else's Github repository. This project is developed with and dependencies are managed by Poetry. The directory structure is there, pyproject.toml is there, poetry.lock is there.

I have set up poetry on my local PC. And now what?

I have gone through 473 tutorials and *all* tell me how to set up a *new* Poetry project. In the best case they also tell how to create a new repo on Github, and create a new Poetry project out of it. Some explain how to migrate an existing non-Poetry project to Poetry.

I don't want to. This is what I want:

- Clone a project which is developed using Poetry
- Run the Python application, find the bug, whatever, change the code retest, and commit to git.
- Just as the upstream developer did when he was working on this project.

I know how to use Git. I know how to use Github. I have installed Poetry and created a new test project. I can run it, I have a virtual environment, I can use Poetry shell.

I just don't know how to clone an *existing* Github project and continue developing in the Poetry environment.

I am using a Linux platform but I think the question is platform independent.

Comment: just go in the directory and type `poetry install` ? That should set up the virtualenv (then you can use `poetry run` and stuff)

Comment: There is no Poetry environment until you use `poetry install`. What comes with the repository are just configuration files used *by* `poetry` to set that environment up.

Comment: It's not clear what virtual enironment you are referring to in your first post-bullet-point paragraph. Typically, you don't use a single virtual environment for multiple projects; each project gets its *own* virtual environment.

Comment: @Nephanth , chepner. That might been what I have been looking for. I will try it out.

Comment: @chepner. I understand that each project has its own virtual environment. Which is exactly the point of Poetry. My problem is how to get to that virtual environment from a freshly cloned git repo. Which is hopefully solved by your first comment.

Comment: https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#install

Answer (score 0):

```
poetry install
poetry run python YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME.py
```

Just extending answer from comments @tbrugere @chepner

Comment: I asked this question 10 months ago. I remember that I have been able to run and modify the code. So at a point I must have been able to complete installation. However if I had to do it again today I would fail and start inventing again how. So for the sake of completeness of your answer, are these the steps?. Clone the repo, install poetry, descend into the repo and poetry run python my_script.py?

Comment: Yes exacly @JohannesLinkels